# How to increase performance of loop operation

Tags: r, performance, loops, runtime

I have a problem with the performance of my R code which checks my data frame for combinations with certain conditions.
For each row in my data frame I need all the combinations where the variable "A" of that row is greater or equal to the variable "B" of all the other rows. In the end I need a matrix which consists of 3 columns with all the combinations:

1. column: number of the row from variable A
2. column: number of the row where the variable B is smaller than A
3. column: -1

And I need this checked for every row. Maybe my problem gets clearer when you see my code.

```
Z <-data.frame(index1=NA,index2=NA,index3=NA)

for(i in 1:nrow(my.data)){

  interim_result <- my.data[i,"A"] >= my.data$B
  if(sum(is.na(interim_result))!=length(interim_result)){

    Y <- rbind(rep(i, sum(interim_result*1)), which(interim_result == TRUE), rep(-1, sum(interim_result)))
    print(i)
    Y <- t(Y)
    colnames(Y) <- c("index1","index2","index3")
    Z <- rbind(Z,Y)
  }
}
```

I checked my code and it works perfectly but it is just too slow. My data frame has around 350K rows and the computation takes forever.
Has anyone an idea I can speed this up?

Comment: You're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398) & [Row-oriented workflows in R with the tidyverse](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows)

Comment: What are you going to do with the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer()` and `which()`.

```
set.seed(1)
n_rows <- 10
my.data <- data.frame(A = rnorm(n_rows), B = rnorm(n_rows))

mat <- which(outer(my.data[['A']], my.data[['B']], '>='), arr.ind = T)
colnames(mat) = c('index2', 'index1')

mat[, c('index1', 'index2')]

      index1 index2
 [1,]      1      4
 [2,]      2      4
 [3,]      2      7
 [4,]      2      8
 [5,]      2      9
 [6,]      3      2
 [7,]      3      4
 [8,]      3      5
 [9,]      3      7
... a total of 39 rows
```

I didn't include `index3` because it's a constant. If it's always -1, there's not much use for it.

I was able to get a lot of speed with a loop by adding an ID to the original data.frame and using an `lapply`. That allowed me to skip the `which` call as well as not have to worry about pre-allocating for `Z`

```
  my.data$ID <- seq_len(nrow(my.data))
do.call(rbind
        , lapply(seq_len(nrow(my.data))
                 , function (i) {
                   interim_result <- my.data[['ID']][my.data[i, "A"] >= my.data[['B']]]
                   if (length(interim_result) != 0) {
                     cbind(index1 = i,index2 = interim_result,index3 = -1)
                   }
                   }
                 )
)
```

Finally, if you're into `data.table`, you can use a non-equi join.

```
  dt <- as.data.table(my.data)

  dt[, ID := seq_len(.N)]

  dt[dt 
     , on = .(A >= B)
     , .(index1 = i.ID, index2 = ID, index3 = -1)
     , allow.cartesian = T
     ]
```

**Performance**
10 row data.frame:

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr     min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
   original_loop 12607.5 12687.6510 13420.3960 12843.0520 13260.4010 17939.301    20
      optim_loop   412.5   439.4515   695.5263   451.2510   462.0020  5345.802    20
          dt_way  3053.0  3140.7510  3269.0610  3268.9010  3351.2010  3667.601    20
 outer_statement    48.5    53.9005    65.7108    70.6505    72.7515    75.701    20
```

100 row data.frame:

```
Unit: microseconds
            expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
   original_loop 42241.600 43560.001 48111.291 46051.7515 48297.301 79910.601    20
      optim_loop  3888.601  4010.551  4775.211  4107.6010  4299.400  9010.601    20
          dt_way  3356.902  3595.601  3857.906  3752.8505  3966.701  5330.101    20
 outer_statement   304.901   312.401   344.661   332.5005   348.701   473.000    20
```

1,000 rows - dropping the original loop:

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
      optim_loop 55.0290 58.18355 60.50015 60.08140 62.47300 66.6332    20
          dt_way 29.1114 29.66050 32.19182 30.00790 30.88125 45.7993    20
 outer_statement 24.2323 24.44935 26.87686 24.64055 27.48775 35.9967    20
```

10,000 rows:

```
Unit: seconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      optim_loop 2.233144 2.277568 2.401055 2.382523 2.496764 2.615275     5
          dt_way 3.622701 3.638953 3.660230 3.639226 3.649577 3.750691     5
 outer_statement 3.250272 3.353263 3.369732 3.375544 3.409773 3.459810     5
```

My computer falls apart after that. Surprisingly to me, the optimized loop starts to make some headway.